# Is using a function that assigns to a null pointer using the null pointer as an argument valid in C?

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to insert into the front of a linked list and also return an allocated head for when head is NULL, but it seems to only work in the event that head is not NULL.

essentially, if

```
node* x = NULL;
```

is

```
x = addfront(x, 3)
```

valid?

Comment: What do you mean "it only works if head is not NULL"? what does it do when it "doesn't work"? Also what does `addfront()` do/return?

Comment: It may or may not be valid depending on the code inside `addfront`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is using a function that assigns to a null pointer using the null pointer as an argument valid in C?

It depends on `addfront` contents. As long as you don't dereference `x` in `addfront`, it is perfectly valid, because dereferencing a null pointer is an undefined behavior.

> it seems to only work in the event that head is not NULL.

We need `addfront` source code. If you don't dereference `x`, the error is elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Null pointers are ok as long as you don't try to dereference them.

Something like

```
node* x = NULL;
x = NULL;
```

Is perfectly fine.